# Contracts, like humans, expire?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Lockdown: I warn you, Mr. Attinger of Earth, an alliance is a contract, and **contracts, like humans, expire**.
>
> Attinger: On this planet, we have a saying. "The enemy of my enemy is
>   my friend."
>
> Lockdown: I also have a saying. "I don't care."
>
> -- *Transformers.Age.of.Extinction.2014*

This bold line sounds odd to me. Contracts can expire, but humans can expire?

I kind of think that's a typo and the line should be **like humans' (contract)**.

What do you think?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expire#Verb

Comment: Your suggested fix doesn't make much sense to me. Human life isn't a contract. It's a gift.

Comment: I thought so, but OALD and Macmillan say it's literary in that sense. @JanDvorak

Comment: Lockdown, rather than equating that humans expire to that contracts expire, equated that contracts expire to that humans expire. This reflects that to them (him?), from their (his?) alien point of view, the fact that humans expire is even more trivial than that contracts expire, or at least Attinger should be aware of the fact or it would be easier for Attinger to take it in (that humans expire).

Comment: This seems like general reference - did you consult dictionaries before posting? They might be conflating two sense of the verb, which might be confusing, but there's nothing in your post to suggest this - is that what's happened?

Comment: Yes, of course. I thought that to mean 'die' it's literary. @jimsug

Comment: @Kinzle can you please provide links to the dictionaries you used? Or references, if they're hard-copy dictionaries? Also, what do you think "literary" means? It doesn't mean it's strictly and rigidly restricted to the domain of the written word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"In this world nothing can be said to be certain, except death and taxes." ~ Benjamin Franklin

> Lockdown: I warn you, Mr. Attinger of Earth, an alliance is a
>   contract, and contracts, like humans, expire.

What this quote is saying, is that contracts have an end. That ending is when they expire. Humans also have an ending, when they die. Expire can mean to come to an end. So saying a human has expired, or can expire, is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

"Expire" is a relatively uncommon, but not unheard of, word for "die". If you say, "Mr Jones expired last year", that means he died last year.

The sentence as given might be considered to be a borderline play on words. Obviously a contract expiring is a very different thing from a person expiring.